# Biblatex induced headache: Bibliography bst style not found

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm new to LaTeX and have been trying to get my document to use a specified `.bst` bibliography style file, but to no avail. I downloaded my preferred `.bst` file (`amnat.bst`) from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/esalatex/files-for-download) into the same folder as my document. I've fruitlessly tried various combinations to try to get it to work (including `\bibliographystyle{amnat}`). I'm not sure if it's a matter of different libraries clashing or what, but I'm incredibly frustrated. I've also tried just setting the bibstyle to equal `plain` and it still doesn't work (also `\bibliographystyle{plain}`).

When I run:

```
pdflatex myTexDocument
```

I get the error message:

```
!Package biblatex Error: Style 'amnat' not found.
```

Also,

```
\RequireBibliographyStyle{\blx@bbxfile}
```

And (after pressing the Return key):

```
!Package biblatex Error: No driver found.
```

When I run the document without the extra `bibstyle=amnat` parameter for biblatex, I do not run into any errors.

Here is an abridged version of myTexDocument.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none,natbib=true,bibstyle=amnat]{biblatex}
\usepackage[pagebackref=false,hidelinks]{hyperref}  %For cross-referencing papers to biliography
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   %Add images
\usepackage{setspace}   %Set line-spacing
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2.25cm]{geometry}   %Set document margins
\usepackage{amsmath}    %For mathematic formulas
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{pdflscape}  %For configuring page orientation
\usepackage{varwidth,array,ragged2e}    %To adjust table row heights accordingly
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathptmx}   %Set font so compatible with math font too
\usepackage{titlesec}   %For adjusting section headings
\usepackage{paralist}   %For lists
\addbibresource{../../../../Bibtex/library.bib} %Load bibiliography

\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries\large}
{}{0em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\normalfont\itshape}
{}{0em}{}[--- ]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*2}{0pt}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}
    \input{titlePage} %My title page document
    \raggedright    %Left Justify document
    \setlength{\parindent}{0.6cm}   %Set paragraph indent
    \doublespacing
    \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Summary}
        \begin{abstract}
            Blahblah \autocite{Webb2002,Graham2008}
        \end{abstract}      
    \section{Conclusion}
        Blah blah
    \phantomsection %Create a hyperlink to the References section in Table of Contents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
    \printbibliography

    \input{tables} %This is just a document with tables
\end{document}
```

Comment: `biblatex` does not use `.bst` files (afaik one of the main goals for the development was to get rid of the bst language and instead just use latex commands for formatting). maybe you want to read the [biblatex tag description](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/biblatex/info) or an [introductory question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `biblatex`, you can't use traditional `.bst` style files. Instead, you have to use either one of the bibliography styles that ship with `biblatex` or a third-party style  specifically written for this package (e.g., [biblatex-dw](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-dw)). Also, with `biblatex`, the `\bibliographystyle` command does nothing but produce a warning.

If there's no exact `biblatex` equivalent to `amnat.bst`, have a look at [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) to create one yourself.