# How to change the bibliography style of this template to IEEE

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style

I am using the following [thesis template](https://github.com/mcmanigle/OxThesis). I need to change the reference style to IEEE style. This is the script that runs with the reference style that I need to change:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{ociamthesis}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}

%%%%% BIBLIOGRAPHY SETUP

\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none, backend=bibtex, doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references}

\newcommand*{\bibtitle}{References}

% This makes the bibliography left-aligned (not 'justified') and slightly smaller font.
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\raggedright\small}


\title{Test Title}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
I cite this~\cite{preece1994human}


\setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt} % JEM: Single-space References

{\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{#1}%
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={\bibtitle}]}

\end{document}
```

In order to change the style,  Iremoved the follwoing two lines from the above script:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none, backend=bibtex, doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{references}
```

and replaced them with this:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}
```

But I get the following errors:

```
line 18: \bibfont undefined. \renewcommand*{\bibfont}
line 32: Undefined control sequence. \printbibliography
: No file Oxford_Thesis.bbl.
line 26: Citation `preece1994human' on page 1 undefined
: There were undefined references.
```

How can I make the above template script to use IEEE reference style. Note that I placed the IEEE required `.sty` and `.bst` files before I compile, still getting the errors.

**EDIT:**

To clarify why adding `style=ieee` does not give the desired output here is some clarification:

If I have this bibliography entry:

```
@misc{smith09,
    author = {Smith, James},
    title = {Obama inaugurated as President},
    date = {2009},
    note = {accessed Jun. 12, 2009},
    url = {https://www.cnn.compolitics},
}
```

According to [IEEE](https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf) (check section P Websites), it should appear like this (note the double quotations in the title of the website):

> [1](https://github.com/mcmanigle/OxThesis) J. Smith, “Obama inaugurated as president,” accessed Jun. 12,
>   2009. [Online]. Available: https://www.cnn.compolitics

The above output is what I get if I use IEEEtran in the Latex script. But, in the thesis template, the same bibliography entry appear like this in the references part (with italic and no quotations mark in the title):

> J. Smith, *Obama inaugurated as president*, accessed Jun. 12, 2009,
>   2009. [Online]. Available: https://www.cnn.compolitics.

If I use @online in the entry instead of @misc, it removes the italic from the title, but does not add quotations marks, and it appears like:

> J. Smith. (2009). Obama inaugurated as president. accessed Jun. 12,
>   2009, [Online]. Available: https://www.cnn.compolitics.

How can I make the reference using the thesis template appear to the same way in the IEEEtran (i.e. the website title is non-italic and with quotations)?

Comment: Just replace  `style=numeric` (which is the default, b.t.w.) with `style=ieee`. Biblatex doesn't use .bst files.

Comment: @Bernard  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Off-topic: You should probably replace `\addbibresource{references}` with `\addbibresource{references.bib}`.

Comment: @Bernard Would you mind writing up a short answer here (you could link to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61956/35864 for a '`biblatex` does not use `.bst` files' explanation).

Comment: If you find that `biblatex-ieee` does not produce the output the IEEE wants, open an issue at https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues. Include a *short* (minimal) example (one that uses a standard class like `article` and only loads the minimum number of packages required to see the output).

Comment: I have *very* reluctantly done that. I think it is extremely helpful for people to have an easy way to find out exactly when (and also how) an issue like this was fixed.

Comment: (And if you don't mind me saying, if someone really wanted to make the link between your two profiles they could probably do that even without me linking the exact question.)

Comment: Note that you can disassociate your account from posts on TeX.SX (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732) and you may be able to do the same on GitHub, so if you are concerned about the link being made, you have some options open to you.

Comment: @moewe no problem. Last question plz. How can I get that specific update without updating my whole Ubuntu system. I use TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/Debian), TexStudio editor, and pdflatex compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You  can have  the specifications of the IEEE  bibliography style with  `biblatex`, simply using

```
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
```

in the place of `[style=numeric]`, and  using the `bib` extension in `\addbibresource{references.bib}`  (contrary to the  `bibtex` command `bibliography{references}`), as  @Mico pointed in his comment.

Also,  `biblatex` does not use `.bst` files, but `.bbx` files for the bibliography styles, `.cbx` files for the citation styles and `.lbx`  files for language-dependent strings. You can find more explanations in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61956/biblatex-induced-headache-bibliography-bst-style-not-found) pointed at by @moewe

Comment: Unfortunately, after trying it, it does not give me the desired format the I used to get when I use the `IEEEtran.bst`. For example, in `@misc` reference type where I used to use to refer to web references, when using your solution, the web document title gets italized (italic font) while it should not (based on IEEE standard) and they are not italized when I use the IEEEtran. Is there a way to allow me use the original IEEEtran?

Comment: Did you try with the `@online` type? Other than this, it is easy to patch biblatex styles to make some modifications. Could you post a short (compilable) document, explaining the details you'd like to change?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the `biblatex-ieee` package fixed the posted problem and the `@online` bibliography entry should be good for an IEEE conformant format now.